# Check type of interrupt using by PCI device (MSI/INT)

Tags: driver, interrupt, pci

How can I check the type of interrupt using by PCI device? For example I have the remapped disk plug into PCI slot and I would like to check what type of interrupt (MSI-x or INT-x) device driver using.

Thanks a lot for answers

Answer (score 0):

The /proc/interrupts file in Linux shows interrupt type, counts, handler registered for that interrupt.
An example of /proc/interrupts is like this:

```
2287:         13         18         28         49   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:lsc
2288:       9141     136551      21455     238464   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v7-Tx
2289:      48562     109176      24880     135639   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v6-Tx
2290:     107570    3702139      75813    3727686   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v5-Tx
2291:      89445    9720752     132501    4888981   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v4-Tx
2292:     137766     210305      24363     145395   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v3-Rx
2293:      67075    7653882      70646   15840483   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v2-Rx
2294:      89234    4985296      78648    6575514   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v1-Rx
2295:     114302     232087      56105     256490   PCI-MSI-edge  eth0:v0-Rx
```